# How to run CLI command in docker Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, apache, docker

I am stuck with docket installed by my client. Whenever i'm running command it says not available and when i tried to run external php file from Magento root its throwing following error

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.:/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php') in /bitnami/magento/htdocs/vendor/autoload.php on line 5
```

Any idea?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/docker/docker-development.html

Comment: above article may help you